# Make postgresql query faster

Tags: sql, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, query-optimization

I have a Query that filters Events by different properties. The query was tested with 1 million events and it took 13 seconds to complete the request.
There are two Queries.
The first Query filters the events with pagination, like it will return the last 50 results that exists.
The second Query counts all events that matches the given filter. The second Query exists so that the frontend knows how many entries exist overall show in the table how many pages the tables has.
It will only take half of the time when I remove the count query.
Also it is important to filter events by regexps. So maybe thats what it slows down.
Currently there is a index over the date and the sourceid. May anyone can give me a hint on how to improve the performance on this query?

**ERD**
[image]

**Query**

```
SELECT DISTINCT event.* FROM Event AS event 
LEFT JOIN event_unit eventunit ON (event.id = eventunit.event_id) 
LEFT JOIN event_newState newStateId ON (event.id = newStateId.event_id) 
LEFT JOIN event_oldState oldStateId ON (event.id = oldStateId.event_id) 
  WHERE unit_id IN :unitIdsParam AND (
    (event.sourceId ~ :sourceIdRegexParam0 AND newStateId ~ :newStateIdsRegexParam0) 
      OR 
    (event.sourceId ~ :sourceIdRegexParam1 AND newStateId ~ :newStateIdsRegexParam1 AND oldStateId ~ :oldStateIdsRegexParam1)
  ) 
AND event.date >= :startDateParam AND event.date <= :endDateParam 
ORDER BY event.date DESC
```

**EventEntity**

```
@Entity(name = EventEntity.ENTITY_NAME)
@Table(name = EventEntity.TABLE_NAME, indexes = { @Index(name = "date_sourceid_index", columnList = "date DESC, sourceId", unique = false) })
public class EventEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Nullable
    private Long id;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE", name = DATE_COLUMN_NAME, nullable = false)
    private Date date = new Date(0);

    @Column(name = SOURCE_ID_COLUMN_NAME, nullable = false)
    private String sourceId = "";

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = EVENT_NEW_STATE_TABLE_NAME, joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = EVENT_ID_COLUMN_NAME))
    @Column(name = NEW_STATE_ID_COLUMN_NAME)
    public Set<String> newStateIds = new HashSet<>();

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = EVENT_OLD_STATE_TABLE_NAME, joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = EVENT_ID_COLUMN_NAME))
    @Column(name = OLD_STATE_ID_COLUMN_NAME)
    public Set<String> oldStateIds = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = UnitEntity.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = EVENT_UNIT_TABLE_NAME, joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = EVENT_ID_COLUMN_NAME) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = EVENT_UNIT_TABLE_UNIT_ID_COLUMN_NAME) })
    private Set<UnitEntity> units = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Comment: You can turn all those joins into EXISTS conditions, then you can get rid of the (probably costly) DISTINCT operator

Comment: See [this article](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/pagination-problem-total-result-count/#total-count) for a discussion of the total result set count.

Comment: What's the purpose of `DISTINCT` in the query? I think there's something you are not understanding correctly about it.

Comment: To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your table definitions, your index definitions, at least some sample regular expressions, and the output of EXPLAIN. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Comment: For your regex searches you probably need [trigram indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html#id-1.11.7.44.8) . Hard to know for sure without more information.